# Proof in Oksendal Book

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I'm stack into a proof of Oksendal's Book. Page 182, equation (9.3.7). 
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of all real $\mathcal{M}_{\infty}$-measurable functions (sigma algebra generated by $X_t$, $t \geq 0$). For $t \geq 0$ we define the shift operator $\theta_t: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ as follows: 
$
\theta_t \eta = g_1(X_{t_1+t}) \dots g_k(X_{t_k+t}),
$
where $\eta=g_1(X_{t_1}) \dots g_k(X_{t_k})$ ($g_i$ Borel measurable, $t_i \geq 0$). 
Let $\alpha \leq T$ be a stopping time ($T$ is a stopping time). We have that 
$
\theta_{\alpha} \Big(\int_{0}^{T}F^u(Y_r)dr\Big) = \int_{\alpha}^{T}F^u(Y_r)dr.
$
Using the approximation proposed in the book I don't understand why the integral is from $\alpha$ to $T$ and not $T +\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ in the situation you refer to is not just any old stopping time, but a *terminal time*, meaning that on the event $\{\alpha<T\}$ you have $T=\alpha+\theta_{\alpha}T$. (This terminal time property it true of all exit times like $T=\tau_D$.)